# StringBuilder taking time to store String value

Tags: java, string, hadoop, hdfs, stringbuilder

I have my logs being stored into a StringBuilder Object . There are almost 214873 lines that are getting stored. Each time when the code finds an error  , the error message is  stored in StringBuilder object and is appended for next error and so.

Finally when all the error message is logged. The lines in the StringBuilder object is written into hdfs. The issue I am  facing is ,  it takes 6 hours to stored the complete error messgges into the StringBuilder object.Is there any way that I can reduce the storage time so as to run the code fatser in production cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing it like that?

Comment: Just because I cannot use logger in this case. We don't have log4j setup in our cluster.

Comment: I think you need to explain the background a bit better, because it's not at all clear why you'd want to be storing log entries in memory of all places, let alone a giant string.

Comment: How long are your log messages? How much memory is consumed by your process, and how much the machine has? Did you consider writing the messages to a temporary file?

Comment: Don't store all your messages in a `StringBuilder`. Even if you don't want to set up logging properly, you could store a list of strings instead of one massive `StringBuilder`.

Comment: logging should be the way to go anyways. But you could also open a Textfile, append your string and close your file. The idea of loging is to seperate the logged information from your programm memory. If you shut down your cluster all the logdata is lost in process, thats ridiculus.

Comment: You should be able to store 200K lines into a StringBuilder in a round a 1 second. If it is taking longer than that, your lines are either very long (which is unlikely given you can only add 2 GB to a StringBuilder) or the program is spending almost all it's time doing something else.

Comment: Hi, Storing the lines in a list and appending the list each time, worked for me. It took 1 min hardly.Finally when all the errors are written into the list. The list is printed into the log file.

Comment: Why is 3 negative votes to this question? Just wanted to know if there is any specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size I could add to a StringBuilder was Integer.MAX_SIZE-2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
    while (sb.length() < maxSize)
        sb.append(' ');
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Took " + time / 1e3 + " second to create a StringBuilder of " + sb.length());
}
```

This prints

```
Took 7.415 second to create a StringBuilder of 2147483645
```

This is writing just one character at a time, so it really should be taking any longer than that.